# How to revert toggle button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a toggle button. Here is the code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch

In my javascript code - I read the 'checkbox' value. If the value is true then I add another div and this another div also has a close button. When the close button is hit, I remove this newly added div from the dom.

So far this all works fine.

I also want to toggle back the button. I am setting up the value to false with the following line:

```
document.getElementsByName("addUserConfirmation").checked = false;
```

It does set the value to false, but the toggle button still remain blue. How do I set it back to off?

Here is the code snippet:

```
function removeCardRevertToggleButton(button, container) {
    var parentContainer = document.getElementById(container);
    jQuery(parentContainer).children().remove();
    document.getElementsByName("addConfirmation").checked = false;
}

<div class="boxStyle">
    <span class="closeButton" requestid="" onclick="removeCardRevertToggleButton(this, &quot;inviteContainerContext&quot;)">×</span>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u9y2w8ev/15/

When close ('x') button is clicked, I want to switch the toggle button to off.

Comment: looks like it has something to do with CSS not being updated though the value is changed.

Comment: Yeah, I think it uses '.slider:before'. How do I set the Pseudo-element. How do I set it back?

Comment: If there is no special situation that requires using Javascript, I can only recommend you to do this with CSS. https://codepen.io/iamturner/pen/xVezWr

Comment: can you share jsfiddle or codepen or anything I might be able to debug and help you with query?
Ideally it should work exactly like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch, if all code is perfectly added :)

Comment: Updated my post with jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("addConfirmation")` returns an array (Element**s**). You have to access an array element like this
`document.getElementsByName("addUserConfirmation")[0].checked`

```js
function removeCardRevertToggleButton(button) {
  document.getElementsByName("addUserConfirmation")[0].checked = false;

}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="addUserConfirmation" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

  <div class="boxStyle">
    <span class="closeButton" onclick='removeCardRevertToggleButton(this)'>×
    </span>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated fiddle as https://jsfiddle.net/k086xnpd/

```
    HTML Code:
    <body>

     <label class="switch">
       <input type="checkbox" id="test" name="addUserConfirmation" checked>
       <span class="slider round"></span>
     </label>

    <div class="boxStyle">
     <span class="closeButton"  onclick='removeCardRevertToggleButton(this)'>×
     </span>
    </div>

   </body>
```

---

```
JS Code:
    function removeCardRevertToggleButton(button) {
    alert("Clicked, new value = " + button.checked);
    //var parentContainer = document.getElementById(container);
    //jQuery(parentContainer).children().remove();

    document.getElementById("test").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("test").addClass('slider:before');
}
```

Hoping that is what you were looking for :)